# Getting Authorization Token in htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project that sends all site requests to a gatekeer.php, and gatekeeper checks authorization level, if user is authorized it sends back to requested I need in htaccess that if page is already checked by gatekpper then let otherwise redriect to gatekeeper.

if user is not authorized gatekeeper itself will send to nonaccess page.

so, only thing required in htaccess if requested pages is checked by gatekeeper or not.

I am not sure how to get this done in htaccess

Comment: Is there any special reason you choose htaccess to validate the Yes/No condition apart from DB entry or something else?

Comment: @Sudip Pal Definitly DB will be used to store user rights, and once user is logged in gatekeeper will definitly match authorization level stored in DB, 
HTACCESS is only for redirection of all requests to gatekeeper, all test will be pefromed at gatekeeper, and then gatekeeper will send user back to requsted url

Comment: Kam, as per my understanding, htaccess is a static file, if you need validation using htaccess you need to add manually all the key or you can add similar match string as authorization key in that file, but this process will cost you more. Lets see if anyone has any better solution on that.

Comment: I have diffrend ideas on that but I am not sure how to get this done in htaccess

Comment: http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net

Comment: I cound not figure this out, how to use with my issue